# FB request to join a group, going around their official SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i need to join a FB group automatically, and i see some of the features i need are not supported by the official SDK, i have looked at their request on a group join, which looks like this.

[image]

ref is irrelevant, and group_id and __user are easy to obtain, but the rest of the parameters are a little more tricky.

I have attempted to find ttstamp in the html output or the function which generates it, without luck.

I also assume that the endpoint ajaxify is called on the href click, i cannot seem to find it.

```
<a href="#" ajaxify="/ajax/groups/membership/r2j.php?ref=group_jump_header&amp;group_id=389351751078062" rel="async-post"><i class="_3-8_ img sp_7__c4BN-XgT sx_77e807"></i>Bliv medlem af gruppen</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**For anyone else venturing down this path, just use SELENIUM, their unofficial API is tricky as hell.**

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Graph API does not provide a way to join groups.

You can see the reference for the API here and all methods relating to a group in the following document:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group

You should not try to use any unofficial method to add users to groups.